# How to save object according to a key which is hash created from tuple or list which numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, hash

My work takes a lot of computational time.

So I want to save each calculated result according to key, for example, a hashed key which generated by parameter which consist of a tuple include numeric, numpy.ndarray, etc.

To solve this assignment, I try to save result(for example, model of machine learning) according to a key, for example, it is hashed key generated from tuple or list which numpy.ndarray below code.

But I could not get hashed key from the tuple object include numpy.ndarray.

```
# Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# generating model of SVM
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.LinearSVC()
key_m=(iris.data, iris.target)
clf.fit(*key_m) # learn form the data according to parameter.

d = shelve.open("testDB")
# save object according to key(key_m)        
d[hash(key_m)]=clf ## xx <- Error occurred.
# load object according to key(key_m)    
clf_cron=d[hash(key_m)]

# Compare with base and retrieve    
if clf==clf_cron:    
    print("Equal\n")
else:
    print("Not Equal\n")
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.
I am sorry late for repley.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy's ndarray object doesn't have a hash method, but you can use md5 or something similar:

```
import md5
m = md5.new()
m.update(iris.data)
m.update(iris.target)
key_m = m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Than you for your answer. It is good answer. Is it difficult to generate hash from objects in list or tuple etc. in a lump?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I could preform my objective.